# Basic memory management: Calling [super dealloc] in dealloc method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, dealloc

If I have a stack of views controlled by a view controller, and a view's dealloc (containing `[super dealloc]`) method is called when I pop the view from the view stack, does that mean I don't have to release the view controller where it was created?

I ask because I originally was releasing the views after creation and pushing them to the navigation controller, except I continually get "overreleased" errors when I include `[viewController release]`. Without that statement, the navigation controller works fine, and the analyze function in XCode doesn't complain about a potential memory leak.

Any sort of explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: An example of where this occurs

```
 OnePlaceViewController *mapView = [[OnePlaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:YES];
```

Normally I would call `[mapView release]` after I push to the navigation controller (in my understanding of memory management, anyway), but I end up with a crash later in my app if I keep the line in there.

Comment: [mapView release] is OK after pushing it to the navigationController. You should be doing that. If later the app crashes, most likely it is because you have released the vc again. Take a look at the navigationController's lifecycle, who is retaining the navController? You should also check at that object's lifecycle too.

Comment: So you're saying that the problem might be that something within OnePlaceViewController might be being overreleased? Also I should say that in this particular case, it crashes when I exit the app and let it run in the background, then try to open it again without quitting the process and restarting it (on the simulator, if that matters). Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never, ever call `-dealloc` directly. The only thing close is the call to `[super dealloc]`, and that should only be called in your own `dealloc`. If you call `dealloc` directly, you should expect a crash later.

If you meant to say `[viewController release]`, then that indicates you have a mismatch somewhere of retains and releases. You should release what you retain. See [Three Magic Words](http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6) for more explanation and links to the full docs. They're not hard, but you must follow them consistently.

**EDIT** If you alloc, you should release when you're done with the object. This doesn't mean "when the object should be destroyed." This means "when *you* are done with the object." If other parts of the system still want the object, they'll retain it. Retain what you want, release what you're done with.

In your example, you should `release` the `mapView`. You've handed it to the nav controller, and now you're done with it. If you're crashing in releasing it, you're probably over-releasing somewhere else. The most likely place is one of `OnePlaceViewController`'s ivars, or one of it's owned-object's ivars.

Start with the static analyzer (Cmd-Shift-B in Xcode 4), and see if it finds your overrelease. It doesn't do a good job of finding ivar overreleases, though. Then, make sure you *always* use accessors except in `init` and `dealloc` (and `init` is controversial). Accessing your ivars directly is the #1 cause of messed up memory management, which is the #1 cause of crashes.

Do not just randomly insert and remove retains and releases. You will tie yourself up in knots. If you fix the crashes, you'll leak. When you fix the leaks you'll crash. You have to find the mistake and fix it. There's no workaround until you upgrade to a system that includes ARC (at which point all of this magically goes away....)

Comment: Good call, I meant `[viewController release]`. I have a console log statement that's called at the beginning of each dealloc method, so I see when each one is called. If I `alloc` an object, even if its dealloc method is called at some point, do I still have to release it? Or is its dealloc method called when I release it?

Comment: `dealloc` is called whenever an object's retain count reaches 0. The retain count is reduced by one whenever you `release` an object or an `autorelease` occurs at the draining of an autorelease pool. So generally, you should always balance a `retain` or an `alloc` with a `release`.

Comment: "always balance a retain or an alloc" or a `copy` or a `new` "with a `release`"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should read the memory mamagement programming guide from Apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Second, you should never be calling [anObject dealloc] directly. The exception is [super dealloc] inside a dealloc method. You will be using release, and autorelease when corresponds.

Again, abide by the memory management rules from Apple and you will be just fine

Comment: I know. See edit above. I meant to say `[viewController release]`.

Comment: Where are you retaining your view controller? Some code snippets would be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1) You should always `release` after pushing a view controller onto a navigation controller or any other "container" view controller, as these controllers will `retain` on the view controller you just `alloc`ed. The exception is if you want to store the view controller in an ivar for later, in which case you should keep the retain. In this case you're likely getting the overreleased crash because something in your `OnePlaceViewController`'s `dealloc` method is being overreleased. Check that method for objects that you have not retained on.

2) Be careful in your use of the words "view" and "view controller". A view is an abstraction of a drawing space, and a view controller is an object that contains the logic to manage a view. If you're using IB and allocating a view controller via a nib (which you appear to be) then all of the view memory management for that view controller should be handled automatically. I would take a good look at whatever objects you're using besides the view in `OnePlaceViewController` to see if anything is released twice.